# Should microservices manage their own media file logics?

Tags: architecture, web-services, microservices, distributed-system

I've heard that when you designing a microservice, the service should includes everything it needs to make them [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) instead of calling each other (*services*).

Based on this idea, should microservice manage their file logics like this:

- UserService:

  - CreateUser()
  - **UploadAvatar**()
- VideoService:

  - CreateVideo()
  - **UploadVideo**()

Or I should create a `FileService`, so I can manage all file logics (*upload, fetch, [AWS server](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_ls)*) in one place?

- UserService:

  - CreateUser(image_file_id)
- VideoService:

  - CreateVideo(video_file_id)
- **FileService**:

  - UploadImage()
  - UploadVideo()

Which also means the user avatar picture needs to be sent to the `FileService` before `CreateUser`.

Comment: Why in the world would the user have to send an avatar picture before creating their account?

Comment: @candied_orange In this example the avatar is not a simple picture file, it's more like a file attachment.

You upload the file first and get the file id, then attach it in the `CreateUser` or `CreateVideo` form.

Comment: So I can separate the file process and the user registration. The unused (or *unlinked*) file will be deleted every x hours.

Comment: I've no idea why a "file attachment" should be a prerequisite to creating a user.

Comment: Maybe it's off-topic but what would you do? Upload the avatar with `CreateUser` form and the `UserService` uploads the avatar to the file server?

Comment: The typical pattern is to create the user and give the user a token that the user passes to all other services so you control access to them and know who's using them.

Comment: `when you designing a microservice, the service should include everything it needs to make them loose coupling instead of calling each other (services).` You don't need to reinvent the wheel over and over for the sake of decoupling. There're other ways to keep services decoupled. Use the right IPC for the matter.

Comment: On the other hand `Upload the avatar with CreateUser form and the UserService uploads the avatar to the file server?` No. Why it should happen all in a single transaction/request? We are speaking about 2 different transactions. So 1. create the user, 2. Upload the file. 3. Never ask UserService for files. UserService doesn't need to know about files. Keep the reference user-file in the FileService if need it.

Comment: What happens if I use a video file ID to create my user?

Comment: @user253751 True, it might need some checks. But since different file types has different metadata, the `video`, `image`, `music`is already been split up in the `FileService`, the ID is also separated. When a client loads the `file_id` from `UserServer`, it's actually linked to `example.com/img/[file_id].png`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from this context. As you present it, I'd be wary of introducing separate services at all. You can achieve loose coupling also within the context of one deployment unit. The services potentially can be classes.

In my experience, microservices or modules with well defined and maintained API add an overhead. It's worth it only if it's outweighed by the benefits. That may be an independent deploy cycle because the services are maintained by different teams. Therefore, if you decide to introduce a service, it should really be as independent as possible. Otherwise you need to coordinate the deployments.

My take would be a `FileService` which has a method `uploadFile` returning the uploaded file identifier.

What's important for loose coupling is that `UserService` and `VideoService` use different storage. Since you mention AWS, it can be a different S3 bucket or at least a different prefix so that each service has complete control over its storage space and you can decide to change the storage with lower risk.

Anyway, if the context is really file uploads, I'd use a class from a shared library. The code should be generic enough. [django-s3-storage](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage) is an example of such library.